# How to get every pixel coordinates from the WM_MOUSEMOVE when the mouse move?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am developing a brush just like the brush in mspaint, but I cannot get all the pixels from 
WM_MOUSEMOVE when the mouse move over the pixels.only can get a set of desultory points.

Comment: Windows doesn't provide all the intermediate points, so about all you can do is guess at intermediate points based on the ones it does supply.

Comment: The simplest thing is to join your desultory points with a line.

Comment: Is the question  about getting the mouse pointer positions (x and y coods) when the mouse is moved?

Comment: @ooga, how to do exactly?

Comment: I used to use the [`LineDDA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145025(v=vs.85).aspx) function for things like this. There's probably a newer way to do that, but knowing the name may give you something to search for that's helpful.

Comment: @user1118321 thank you very mush,I have deal with the problem with the LineDDA function.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `GetMouseMovePointsEx` to get a history of the last 64 mouse points, which may include points that were never delivered to your app via `WM_MOUSEMOVE`.

But you can often improve the performance in this sort of application by ignoring the actual mouse position that `WM_MOUSEMOVE` sends you and instead query the pointer position directly with `GetCursorPos`.

Either way, you'll never get enough resolution from the mouse to draw a smooth joined-up line - the best you can do is draw straight lines (or even interpolate splines) between the coordinates.